# How to get file directory trough .htaccess by using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]`?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, mod-rewrite

How to get file directory trough .htaccess by using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]`?

If .htaccess is located in `http://localhost/some/dir/.htaccess` and I'm opening `http://localhost/some/dir/here/I/use/RewriteRule/`, how I detect value `/some/dir/` without using `RewriteBase` and without manual adding `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/some/dir/`, like value `localhost` I get trough `%{HTTP_HOST}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy Apache still does not have `pathinfo($,PATHINFO_DIRNAME)`, function like has PHP.

So on now there are solution on using `%{REQUEST_URI}`, like this example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /path-dirname/$1 [R=301,L]
```

may reset with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^.+/$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But isn't REQUEST_URI giving you the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use RewriteBase you need to tell mod-rewrite the real Directory Root /var/ww/mysite/some/dir in the rewrite rule. RewriteBase would take the location url and map it to the directory.

So you'll maybe end up with

```
 RewriteRule /var/ww/mysite/some/dir/(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And trying to map some internal variables it may be

```
 RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/some/dir/(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I'm unsure, I rarely use mod_rewrite in .htaccess -- I prefer *Directory* tags, and the file path management can be different in .htaccess (auto removal and adding of directory prefixes). If you do not find a solution try to ask [Servfault](http://serverfault.com), plenty of admins other there.

Comment: This is a hackish solution though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984554/how-to-reference-the-current-directory-from-htaccess-using-mod-rewrite#comment80066401_984641 Apache should give a better way to get the htaccess parent folder uri.