# mod_rewrite for all pages (including subfolders) on a site to a single php page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am in the process of converting my site with many static html pages to a site driven by a database. My problem is that I don't want to lose what google has already indexed, so I would like to rewrite requests to be sent through a php script which lookup the filepath for content in the database. My understanding is that a mod_rewrite would best serve this purpose, unfortunately I have never used it, so I am a bit lost.

What I have:

```
www.domain.com/index.html
www.domain.com/page.html?var=123&flag=true
www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/
www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/index.html
www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/new/test.html
www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/new/test.html?var=123&flag=true
```

What I want (I also probably need to urlencode the path)(passing the full uri is also ok):

```
www.domain.com/index.php?page=/index.html OR www.domain.com/index.php?page=www.domain.com/index.html
www.domain.com/index.php?page=/page.html?var=123&flag=true
www.domain.com/index.php?page=/folder/subfolder/
www.domain.com/index.php?page=/folder/subfolder/index.html
www.domain.com/index.php?page=/folder/subfolder/new/test.html
www.domain.com/index.php?page=/folder/subfolder/new/test.html?var=123&flag=true
```

Here's my first go at it:

```
RewriteEngine On  # Turn on rewriting    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .* # Do I even need this?    
^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

So I tried implementing Ragnar's solution, but I kept getting 500 errors when I use 'RewriteCond $1' or include the '/' on the last line. I have setup a test.php file which will echo GET_["page"] so I know that the rewrite is working correctly. So far I can get some of the correct output (but only when I am not in root), for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If I visit the page http://www.domain.com/page/test/subdirectory/page.html?var=123 it will output 'test/subdirectory/page.html' (missing the querystring, which I need). However, if I use this example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If I visit http://www.domain.com/page/test/subdirectory/page.html?var=123 it will only output 'test.php' which is thoroughly confusing. Thoughts?

Edit #2:

It seems I've been going about this all wrong. I just wanted the ability to use full uri in my php script page. The final working solution to do what I want is the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test.php
```

Then in my php script, I can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get what I need. I knew this should have been easier than what I was trying...

Comment: If Edit #2 was the solution, you should have posted it as a solution, then checked it a few hours later.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to look into the [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), it contains extensive information about rewriting with examples.

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to use something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?page=$1 [L]
```

Which is very similar code to the one you posted. If you want better information, be specific about your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, glad to see I am on the right track. Any tips for urlencoding $1 on the last line?

Comment: @veerman, see [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/blog/software/open_source/apache/mod_rewriting_an_entire_site).

Comment: @veerman, As long as its a transparent redirect (ie not a redirect to a new domain), you don't have to bother passing `$1`. Just do a transparent redirect and you can read the path from your script using the usual ways: `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. C my ans.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for so many lines, it only complicates things.

All you need is 2 lines in `.htaccess`:

```bs
rewriteengine on
#rewriterule-: ar1 path =relative. ar2 if relative, that to rewritebase.
rewriterule !^foo/bar/index\.php$ /foo/bar/index.php
#..assert ar1 dismatches correct url
```

---

**In PHP**

You can output the first input of rewriterule in PHP using:

```
<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

That will give you all the power and allow you to do all things. Simply parse `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` manually and you can `echo` totally different pages depending on the value of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

---

**Sec bugs**

Note that your server may do pathing or buggy pathing before rewriterule. (You can't override this behavior without server privileges.) Eg if the user visits `/foo////` you may only see `/foo/` or `/foo`. And eg if the user visits `///foo` you may only see `/foo`. And eg if the user visits `/a/../foo` you may only see `/foo`. And eg if the user visits `/a//b/../../foo` you may only see `/foo` or `/a/foo` [because buggy production servers treat multiple `/` as distinct in the context of `..`, **no kidding**].

---

**With circuit break**

Rewrite circuit breaks on cin identical to htaccess∙parentfolder∙relative interpreted rewriterule∙arg2. (First off, personally I'd disable circuit breaks to reduce rule complexity but there seems to be no way to do so.)

Circuit-break solution:

```bs
rewriteengine on
#rewriterule-: ar1 path =relative. ar2 if relative, that to rewritebase.
rewriterule ^ /foo/bar/index.php
#..circuit-breaking, so assert ar2 if absolute, htaccess parentfolder =root, else, htaccess parentfolder not in interpreted ar2.
```

---

**Circuit break and rewritebase undesigned use**

Circuit break needs either of:

1. arg2 [of rewriterule] ⇌ absolute. and htaccess parentfolder ⇌ root.
2. arg2 ⇌ relative. and that folder not in interpreted arg2.

So when that folder ≠ root, circuit break needs arg2 ⇌ relative. when arg2 ⇌ relative, circuit break needs⎾that folder ⇌ not in interpreted arg2⏋.

Say we need circuit break and a htaccess parentfolder that's in interpreted arg2, so we edit arg2 via rewritebase:

```bs
rewriteengine on
#rewriterule-: ar1 path =relative. ar2 if relative, that to rewritebase.
rewriterule ^ bar/index.php
#..circuit-breaking, so assert ar2 if absolute, htaccess parentfolder =root, else, htaccess parentfolder not in interpreted ar2.
rewritebase /foo
#..needs to be absolute [</> starting]. pathing [eg </../a/..> and </../..///ran/dom-f/oobar/./././../../..////////.//.>] allowed
```