# Problems with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I decided to use `mod_rewrite` to make my URLs look better. I created very simple rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(profile|contact|help|events|account|logout)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^PlaceOrder/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=mos&gc=$1 [NC]
```

It almost works well but it doesn't. So for example, `[NC]` is supposed to make it case-insensitive. However, for some reason, when I type for example `localhost/Help` in the browser, for some strange reason, it redirects to home page. 
Another issue is with the last rule. If I type in `localhost/PlaceOrder/1` it works as expected and opens `index?p=mos&gc=1`. But after that if I click on, for example, Account button, the browser uses this URL: `localhost/PlaceOrder/account`. Which is wrong. It should only use `localhost/account`. Why is it adding that sub-directory in there? It is only happening after the last rule is used. Prior to using the last rule, all links work well.

Comment: Are you not getting `$_GET['p'] = Help` in `index.php` for `localhost/Help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the `localhost/Help` isn't because of the rules and because of something in your index.php script. There's nothing those rules do that could possibly rewrite `Help` to the home page.

The second issue is a matter of a relative vs absolute URL issue. You're probably using relative links in your pages and because you've changed your relative URL base (which would be `/PlaceOrder/` all relative links will have that prepended to it. You need to either change all your links to absolute URLs (they'd start with a `/`) or add this to your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Isn't that what `RewriteBase` is for?

Comment: @user2395238 nope, that's not what `RewriteBase` does at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it/ It has nothing to do with how your browser interprets the URL base