# Silex 'App\Controller\IndexController' not found on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, silex

My silex project works on local, but when I put it online, I have a NameSpace or Class resolution problem :

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\IndexController' not found in /homepages/40/d453499750/htdocs/myfolder/app/bootstrap.php on line 19

Structure :

```
/  
->myfolder  
    ->app
        ->controller
           ->IndexController.php
        ->bootstrap.php
        ->...
    ->vendor
    ->web
        ->.htaccess
        -> index.php
        -> ...
```

composer.json

```
{
  "minimum-stability":"dev",
  "autoload": { "psr-0": { "App\\": "./" }},
  "require":{
      "silex/silex": "~1.2",
      "symfony/twig-bridge":"2.1.*",
      "twig/twig":">=1.8,<2.0-dev"
 }
}
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myfolder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

boostrap.php

```
<?php

use App\Controller\IndexController;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider;

/* load vendors */
$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
/* unable path() and url() */
$app->register(new UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
/* twig */
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider());

/* load the controllers*/
$loader->add("App",dirname(__DIR__));
$app->mount("/", new IndexController());

return $app;
```

IndexController.php

```
namespace App\Controller {


use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ControllerProviderInterface;

class IndexController implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
...
```

My silex is in a folder but I rewriteBase in .htaccess. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You have folders `app` and `controller`, not `App` and `Controller` like in your namespace.

Comment: I had think about it, but I'm not sure that is a link between namespace and folder name

Comment: What OS are you on? On linux, the file systems are case-sensitive, thus app and App are different directories.

Comment: Your RewriteBase is wrong, rewritebase is relative to URI not filesystem (well, also filesystem but depending on your webroot folder). [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it). PS: Make sure that your webroot is the *web* folder, not *myfolder* folder, otherwise you're making all your project files directly accessible from anywhere

Comment: @mTorres : I'm on a server with multiple projects, so that's why I use myfolder (a folder for each project). In this folder, I have my silex project. I think as you that the problem is in the .htaccess or in the server configuration. "PS: Make sure that your webroot is the web folder" with a vhost or an superior htaccess  ?

Comment: yes, if your webroot is *myfolder* folder, then you definetely need an htaccess to forbid the acces to all non public folders.

Comment: It's ok, I have a htaccess in myfolder wich is pointing in the web folder. And in my web/ folder I have a htaccess wich is making the silex job (pointing on the index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @Maerlyn "You have folders app and controller, not App and Controller like in your namespace."

This made me on the right track !

I have renamed my folders with first letter uppercase and it was worked. But I thought about the Silex vendor wich was working with uppercase namespace and lowercase dirnames...

The solution is in the **composer.json** and more precisely in the **autoload** parameter.

With this functionality, you can **map** your namespaces and your folder  :

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Controller\\": "./app/controller"
    }
  },
```

Here you can find more information :
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

and you can find generated code in the vendor => composer => autoload_psr4 file

```
return array(
    ...
    'App\\Controller\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/controller'),
);
```

With this I can keep lower case folders (as silex default), and uppercase namespaces.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't think about changing to psr4 :)