# Problems configure .htaccess for friendly url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a problem with my .htaccess to use friendly url in my website.

My server structure is:

1. www:

   - test-web (website test code).

     - shop-test.

       - .htaccess
       - others files to my shop website (index, images, etc...)

My .htaccess have the next code to redirect the url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test-web/shop-test    
RewriteRule ^pay$ index.php?section=buy [L]
RewriteRule ^details/(.+)/?$ index.php?section=details&item=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But if I write my url like the next example, doesn't work:

```
<a href='/test-web/shop-test/pay'>go to pay<a>
```

I tried to write others links like "/shop-test/pay", just put "pay" in my link and change the RewriteBase in my .htaccess to "/shop-test" or "/test-web" and anything works.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Do you actually have anything in `test-web`? seems like unnecessary dir.

Comment: Yes, I have there a test website (it a wordpress site)

Comment: ok, well your rewritebase and rewriteengine are in the wrong order btw. They need to come first before any other Rewrite directives. Also take a took at Jon's explanation of using rewritebase with subsubdir's. It should get you going. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it/21348047#21348047