# What's the formula for redirecting links to subfolder htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are SO many questions on this I know, but there always seems to be a lack of complete understanding on my part about htaccess files. My file is really simple (taken from Bluehost as with other projects):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?theglobalhuman.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1
```

My folder structure (in a nutshell) is:

```
root
 |-- app
      |--templates
            |-- admin
            |-- public
 |-- tmp
 |-- www
 |-- .htaccess
```

Where `www` has the index file.

So if I go to `website.com`, things are fine.
If I go to `website.com/something/more`, that works fine, which hits the `templates/public` folder.

However, if I go to `website.com/admin/more`, which goes to the `templates/admin` folder, for some reason the htaccess breaks and inserts **www** into the url. Has anyone ever has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer could be the rewrite_base rule, from [this post by @jonlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it).:

> if it's in the "subdir2" directory, and you go to http://example.com/subdir2/foo, mod_rewrite will mistake the relative path as a file-path instead of a URL-path and because of the R flag, you'll end up getting redirected to something like: http://example.com/var/www/localhost/htdocs/subdir1. Which is obviously not what you want.

I would check out the rest of his answer, it is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still having a hard time. The answer helped me understand more on how to use htaccess, but I'm still stuck. I just edited my question to clarify more.