# Rewrite part of url htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite url with htaccess from

```
https://www.example.com/cozumel/...
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/cozumel-shore-excursions/...
```

I tried like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/cozumel\/(.*) /cozumel-shore-excursions/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line:

```
RewriteRule ^cozumel/$ /cozumel-shore-excursions/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: That whole query string thing is not necessary. You can just pass the `[QSA]` (stands for "query string append") flag and apache will handle including any additional query string parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the leading slash from your rule's pattern :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cozumel/(.*) /cozumel-shore-excursions/$1 [L,R=301]
```