# Codeigniter main domain from Subdirectory: base_url returns sub directory name as well

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to serve my main domain from a sub-directory in the doc_root in a shared Apache/PHP server. The application is developed using Codeigniter and all the urls are dynamically created using base_url() function. The problem is, all the urls have the name of the subdirectory as well. I want to remove it but don't know how to do it.

base_url produces urls like `http://example.com/v2/public_html/page1`.
but I want it to produce `http://example.com/page1`.
Both the above urls serve the correct page however.

This is my directory structure:

```
|-doc_root
   |-v1 
   |-v2
       |-system
       |-application
       |-public_html
         |-.htaccess
       |-.htaccess
   |.htaccess
```

In my config.php file I have setup `$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";`

.htaccess file in doc_root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    v2/public_html/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) v2/public_html/$1    [L]
```

.htaccess in doc_root/v2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public_html/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public_html/$1    [L]
```

And the .htaccess in doc_root/v2/public_html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /v2/public_html
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please help me to get this resolved.

Comment: what did you mean by 'rewrite base ...'.?

Comment: RewriteBase  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it  Just thought it might be helpful in your subdomains folder.  But I see now you already have that.

Comment: You'll have to look at how CI is creating the urls and possibly do them another way with like a global php constant for example. The issue is not really with .htaccess but how you write the urls.  Otherwise youll have to do like a [R] redirect to change the url in the browser.  Which is an additional network hop.  See htaccess will make the modified ( incorrected ) urls map correctly to your site.  You can do the other way around but its more legwork, for your requests.

Comment: I changed the `base_url` helper function to strip the subfolder name, not the correct way though.