# .htaccess Adding HTTPS forcing to existing rewrite rules of subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Probably I'm overseeing something very basic, htaccess is not my field of expertise.

My site is https-only, to achieve this, the root folder / contains these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works just fine. Now we have a new folder called /projects, which contains its own htaccess rules to translate the url in a database query by a file called /projects/project.html

The working htaccess within the folder /projects is:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /projects/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ project.html?project=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I would like to force https connection on this one, because the https rule in the main directory is not applied on /projects if you visit by http://URL directly. Therefore I modified the file to:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /projects/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ project.html?project=$1 [QSA,L]
```

With this, it switches to https, but I keep getting "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

When I change the lines as @thickguru suggested, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It will redirect me to `https://example.com/index.html` right away.

I fiddled around with the settings, also with the information of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it), however still I can't get it to work.

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm giving the correct answer, but phpinfo mentions Apache2, API version 20051115. If I need to look somewhere else, please let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed it the variable you are matching against is **%{ENV:HTTPS}** , so , you can use the following rule in /projects/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache or try a diffrent browser to test this.

Comment: At least now page loads correctly when using https:// in the URL, with the complete code now being 

`RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

RewriteBase /projects/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ project.html?project=$1 [QSA,L]`

I now get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when typing in the http version of the URL.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in Redirect destination. Please see the edit

Comment: Aaah now you point it out, that typo was obvious, stupid I didn't see. This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks a lot every one who contributed. Special thanks to @tickguru for the bounty!

Comment: @starkeen what is `%{ENV:HTTPS}` I mean how it is different from `%{HTTPS}`?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Unlike **{HTTPS}** , **{ENV:HTTPS}** is a user defined variable. You can set it using ENV or SETEnv directive or it can also be set using mod rewrite's E flag.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Also, place this above your your other `RewriteRule`, so that your `.htaccess` will look like:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /projecten/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ project.html?project=$1 [QSA,L]
```

EDIT - Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This does not work, gives error that request will never end.. In address bar the URL has changed to HTTPS variant though

Comment: I've made edits to the code. Please try again with new code. Also, test it with it being below the other `RewriteRule` also.

Comment: I tried it in both orders, plus tried playing with the R=301, L, NE and QSA tags. However, keeps throwing errors. No correct handling of existing rules in combination with HTTPS

Comment: This is still an issue. Any other suggestion? :)

Comment: I've made an edit for you to try @TijnvW. Let me know.

Comment: Aarrrggh this is driving me crazy! Thanks for helping again @thickguru, but unfortunately with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]` it redirects me to the homepage https://example.com. With `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]` I get: error request will never end.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I've started a bounty for you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort mate!

Comment: @tijnvw Clear your browser cache. The rule is ok and it should work.

Comment: @starkeen That's not the problem/solution, I clear cache before every page reload. However, I think it may have something to do with conflicting rules in an other directory, I will update my question.