# I always observe this error "invalid rewrite base" , and my program does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I always see this error:
 (2019-02-07 12:31:48.595 [ERROR] [/home/shopph/domains/example.com/public_html/.htaccess:4] Invalid rewrite base: 'http://example.com/')

My codes in .htaccess are as follow:

```
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase http://example.com/
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The aforementioned error prevent to run my program. I would be appreciated if you help me to tackle my problem.
Best Regards

Comment: You miss something in your `.htaccess` file . Can you post your `.htaccess`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does RewriteBase do and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your situation you have to change:

`RewriteBase http://example.com/`

to

`RewriteBase /`

If it doesn't work, you have to give more details about your goal.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration

Comment: If you are satisfied with my solution, would you consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?