# List directory contents with Apache

Tags: apache, vue.js, vue-router

Let me start by saying that my knowledge of Apache is almost none, so I apologize if I am not using the correct terminology.

I have a website written in Vue, and the routing is taken care by [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org). In their documentation, they specify that in order for the router to work correctly, you have to put this in the `.htaccess` file of your website:

```xml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

From what I have been able to understand, all requests are sent back to the `index.html` file which will take care of loading the correct component based on the path.

My goal is to now allow my website to have a path (let's say `/documents`) which is not picked up by Vue, but instead shows the contents of the directory and allows you to both navigate and download the contents (Like [this](https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Apache-Directory-Listing.png)).

I have tried a few ways, but they all return a 403 or 500 (possibly due to a mistake in my config). I understand that I need to add a `RewriteRule` but all of those that I tried return weird errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after looking through the docs, I was not able to understand how to set it up. I found [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/), and using option #2 I was able to get the directory to at least show up.

I then added the auth to the folder through the `.htaccess` file and added the `.htpasswd` file with the username/password combo

**TLDR**

1. Create the folder in the location you want. In my case it was in `httpdocs/documents`
2. Create a `.htaccess` file where you put the following contents:

```py
# Omit this section if you do not need the auth
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
require valid-user

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
```

3. Create the `.htpasswd` file in the location you specified above. To generate the username/password combo I used [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Any corrections are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple rewrite rules based on what the `RewriteBase` is . In your current set, the rule is applying to the root of the host.

You can add another rule with `RewriteBase /documents/`. More info: [What does RewriteBase do and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition.

So here a dirty explanation:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

So your RewriteConds says that if the given path/url isn't a file (!-f) and not a directory (!-d) then the next rewrite rule  (RewriteRule . /index.html [L]) takes action.

```
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

"." is a wildcard, so all urls will be redirect to index.html.
The [L] flags stops the execution (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

The `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]` stops the execution if the url is index.html.

So, your rewrite rule fulfill your requirements and seems correct.

When you get a 403 you maybe need to add `Options +Indexes` to your config or htaccess.