# How to rewrite URL rules to the root folder but not its subdirectories?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, root, subdirectory

I'm creating a vanity URL/ clean urls for my users. The `.htaccess` rewrite rules are working fine but I'm facing problem with the subdirectories.

Particularly like, when someone types `example.com/user` it works perfectly fine and fetch data from the page `example.com/profile.php?username=user`.
But when somebody browse,`example.com/subdirectory/user`, this also shows the content of `example.com/profile.php?username=user`.

How can I limit the rewrite rules to only my root directory and not its subdirectory so that when someone browse `example.com/subdirectory/user` they will be redirected to `404 Not found` as usual if there is no such file or folder in that subdirectory.

`.htaccess` code is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sounds like you used some overly generic RewriteRule copypasta. Impossible to tell without showing that config and/or the rewrite.log

Comment: Check the post again, I've updated the .htaccess code...

Comment: add `RewriteBase /subdirectory/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does RewriteBase do and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: So what is wrong in the code what can I change in it so that subdirectories would not rewrite url!

Comment: I just want the root folder to rewrite the url and not the subdirectories like **mysite.com/subdirectories/user**

Comment: "But when somebody browse, `example.com/subdirectory/user`, this also shows the content of `example.com/profile.php?username=user`" - this statement was a little misleading, since according to the directives you posted it would have resulted in a rewrite to `example.com/profile.php?username=subdirectory/user`, not simply `username=user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\.]+` is a poor placeholder, that matches almost anything (including path segments).

Since usernames are likely alphanumeric, `\w+` is a better fit:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Btw, typically you'd want more speaking paths like `/user/name…` rather than having a magic lookup in the site root.