# PHP Slim4 on Apache2 gives HttpNotFoundException

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

Links I've seen include:

> https://akrabat.com/running-slim-4-in-a-subdirectory/
>
> https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/slim-4-httpnotfoundexception/3273/18

and some others

I'm trying to setup a Slim4 project on apache2. But trying to access it gives me the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found....

I have my index file in `/var/www/html/_projects/work/calc1/src`.

The following is my calc.conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName calc.mrid.local
    ServerAlias calc.mrid.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/_projects/work/calc1/src

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `.htaccess` located in `src` directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /_projects/work/calc1/src/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

My `index.php` looks like this:

```
// use and require statements...

$container = new Container();
AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$container->set('view', function() {
    return \Slim\Views\Twig::create(__DIR__ . '/public/templates');
});

$app = AppFactory::create();

// even without this line it doesn't work
$app->setBasePath("/_projects/work/calc1/src"); 

$app->add(TwigMiddleware::createFromContainer($app));

// my routes....

$app->run();
```

Has anyone worked with Slim4 on Apache2? If yes, can you please guide me ?

Comment: Please share definition of some routes that result in a `HttpNotFoundException`. Also please provide full exception message, specially the part that says which URL you were trying to reach that did not exist.

Comment: I think because DocumentRoot points to `/var/www/html/_projects/work/calc1/src`, you should avoid putting `RewriteBase /_projects/work/calc1/src/` line in .htaccess. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it/21348047#21348047).

Answer (score 0):

The `src/` directory is actually only meant for the PHP classes and must not be accessible to the web. The apache `DocumentRoot` should point to the `public/` directory which contains your front controller `public/index.php`. Take a look at the [Standard PHP package skeleton](https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton). More details about Slim and apache can be found in this [Slim 4 Tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/05/slim4-tutorial.html).

Comment: i slightly modified my directory structure. i have my index.php in src and have all assets (css, js, images, templates) in public directory. will i have to change all this ?

Comment: just checked the skeleton link...it says that src will have the php files, and public will have web server files