# I'm building a simple php router but i don't know what happens in the ".htaccess" file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, router

I'm building a simple PHP router and I understand the most things except for the things in the ".htaccess" file. If I comment out the things in the ".htaccess" file, nothing changes, or I don't notice anything changing(the contents of the ".htaccess" file is from a tutorial). The ".htaccess" file contains the following things

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

and this is the content from the index.php

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/ROUTER/index.php':
    case '/ROUTER/index.php/home':
         require __DIR__ . '/controller/homeController.php';
         break;
    case '/ROUTER/index.php/about' :
         require __DIR__ . '/controller/shopController.php';
         break;
    default:
         http_response_code(404);
         require __DIR__ . '/controller/404Controller.php';
         break;
}
```

the contents in the homeController.php etc files are just a simple echo with a text. Maybe someone can explain to me what happens in the ".htaccess" file.

Comment: `!-d` and `!-f` mean "if the directory and file don't exist". If you comment them out, all requests go to your router. But if you leave them alone, regular files, such as images, can be accessed without going through your router.

Comment: Note also that use of `.htaccess` is a feature of the Apache web server. If you're using something else like nginx or the PHP built-in server, then this file does nothing.

Comment: and what's about the RewriteBase and RewriteRule

Comment: This is the standard Apache .htaccess file to enable the Front Controller pattern in a PHP app. It basically says, "take any request for a file that doesn't exist and send it to index.php instead of throwing a 404 error". (And then index.php handles whether or not a 404 gets thrown.)

Comment: You got 2 excellent answers already, both to explain mod_rewrite (which often uses regular expressions aka "regex".  I recommend you implement the changes in the answer from @MrWhite.  What you want is to show and accept the url's of either http://www.yoursite.com/router/home or http://www.yoursite.com/home.  In order to accomplish this your own code must present those url's in links and any internal navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Most web servers have logic like this for determining which file to serve:

- If a file exists with a file name that matches the URL path, use that file
- If a directory exists with a name that matches the URL path:

  - If a default file (usually `index.html` or `index.php`) exists in that directory, use that file
  - If configured to show a file listing, do so

Otherwise the web server returns an error status.

---

Many web applications want to implement their own logic for what to show for each URL and implement their own routing rules.  They typically use `.htaccess` to create a [Front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) that passes nearly every request into a single central file that handles its own routing for the web application.  Your `.htaccess` has fairly standard front controller rules that pass most URLs into `index.php`

Breaking it down line by line:

- `RewriteEngine On` -- Enables [mod rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which is an Apache module that uses rules to change which file handles which URLs
- `RewriteBase /` -- Specifies which directory the rules are relative to.  This can usually be omitted because `/` is the default value in `.htaccess` in the document root.  See [What does RewriteBase do and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347768/what-does-rewritebase-do-and-how-to-use-it)
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` -- If the requested URL is not an existing directory
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` -- If the requested URL is not an existing file
- `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]` -- Handle all URLs with `index.php`. A rewrite rule has three sections:

  - The pattern to match against the URL path (`^(.+)$`)

    - `^` is starts with
    - `.+` one or more of any character
    - `$` is ends with
    - `()` parenthesis capture the matched characters as a group that is available in a variable (`$1`).  The parenthesis in this rule could be removed because the variable is never used.
  - The target file that handles the URLs (`index.php`)
  - Flags that modify how the rule works (`[QSA,L]`)

    - `QSA` is query string append to make sure `index.php` has access to anything after the `?` in the URL
    - `L` is last so that any later rewrite rules wouldn't also get executed.

In effect, it uses the default web server logic for files or directories that exist, but pass all other requests to `index.php`.

Answer (score 2):

[@StephenOstermiller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70870061/369434) has done a great job of describing the `.htaccess` file / front-controller process, but I thought I'd address the other issue you raised...

> If I comment out the things in the ".htaccess" file, nothing changes

That's because the format of the URLs you are using (eg. `/ROUTER/index.php/home`) completely negates the need for the `.htaccess` file to begin with. You are calling `index.php` (the "front-controller") directly in the URL itself and passing `/home` as *additional pathname information* (aka. path-info).

The `.htaccess` file is still processed, but the 2nd *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive), which checks that the request does not map to a physical file, fails (`index.php` is a physical file) so the rule is not triggered (it does nothing).

The additional path-info on the URL is available to PHP in the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` superglobal. So, if you are using URLs of the form `/ROUTER/index.php/home` then you could write your front-controller (`index.php`) like this instead (simplified):

```
// URLs of the form "/ROUTER/index.php/home"
$request = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

switch ($request) {
    case '':
    case '/home':
         :
    case '/about' :
         :
}
```

(As noted above, this is *not* making use of `.htaccess`)

---

On the other hand, your `.htaccess` file allows you to have URLs of the form `/ROUTER/home` (or simply `/home`), avoiding you having to include `index.php` in the URL, which is then internally rewritten to `index.php` (by the rule in `.htaccess`). You then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (as in your original script) to access the requested URL in PHP.

For example (simplified):

```
// URLs of the form "/ROUTER/home"
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/ROUTER/':
    case '/ROUTER/home':
         :
    case '/ROUTER/about' :
         :
}
```

However, your existing `.htaccess` file is not configured correctly for this. The `.htaccess` file is assuming `index.php` is located in the document root, but your URLs suggest you have a `/ROUTER` subdirectory, in which `index.php` (the "front-controller") is located.

If your `.htaccess` file is in the `/ROUTER` subdirectory at `/ROUTER/.htaccess` then remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely.

If, however, your `.htaccess` file is located in the document root then you will need to change your `RewriteBase` directive to read:

```
RewriteBase /ROUTER
```

(Setting `RewriteBase /ROUTER` in *both* cases will also work.)